# copy a Sheet from a workbook to another with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**EDIT**

I'm still trying to copy a **Sheet** from a **Workbook** to **another Workbook**, It looks like an easy task but for some reasons I can't do it.
For my tests I made a very basic files and codes : (My Sheet contain a simple Table and a button to run the macro, it's the only macro I have)

***WORKING***

Copying a Sheet to the same Workbook :

```
Sub CopyShtInTheSameWk()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

***NOT WORKING***

*Test n°1 **-----------------------------------------------------***

```
Sub CopyShtToAnotherWb()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\33672\Desktop\test2.xlsm")
 Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=WB.Sheets(1)
 WB.Close SaveChanges:=True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This test just creat a new sheet in the second workbook but didn't copy the content inside.

*Test n°2 **-----------------------------------------------------***

```
Sub CopySheetToAnotherWb()
 Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Workbooks("C:\Users\33672\Desktop\test2.xlsm").Sheets(1)
End Sub
```

I got the error message :

> Run-time error 9 -> Subscript out of range

*Test n°3 **-----------------------------------------------------***

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportWorksheet1()
 Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
 Const dPath As String = "C:\Users\33672\Desktop\test2.xlsm"
 Const dIndex As Long = 4 ' often not such a good idea

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
 Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(sName)

 Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dPath)
 Dim dsh As Object: Set dsh = dwb.Sheets(dIndex) ' could be a chart

 sws.Copy Before:=dsh
 dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I got the error message on the line (Workbooks.Open()) :

> Run-Time error 1004 -> Sorry, we couldn't find the file "C:\Users\33672\Desktop\test2.xlsm"

*Test n°4 **-----------------------------------------------------***

Just copy pasting data of the Table Range to the Sheet of the other workbook.

```
Sub CopyDataIntoAnotherShtOfAnotherWb()
 Dim Wb As Workbook

 Wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\33672\Desktop\test2.xlsm")
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("MyTable").CurrentRegion.Copy
 Wb.Worksheets("Bilan").Range("A1").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
 Wb.Close

End Sub
```

I got the error message on the line of the Workbooks.Open() :

> Run-Time error 1004 -> Sorry, we couldn't find the file "C:\Users\33672\Desktop\test2.xlsm"

**Info**

- The Path of my file test2 is the good one each time.
- I'm working on Excel 2016 in my company computer but had already try to do the same on Microsoft 365 on my personal computer without any difference.

Comment: There is several `UDF` in your code, I think those UDF is the problem in your code now, try modified or test it in standalone `sub`, then you should be able to solve it

Comment: Please, edit your post and show the rest of your code. Probably, the problem is there.

Comment: I just Edit it, no more UDF, the issue is still the same

Comment: You shouldn't use the full path when referring to a workbook in the `Workbooks` collection, you only need the workbook name.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks Norie, does I need to add the name with the extension ?

Comment: I found something weird on my code, I try to fix it and I come back here later

Comment: I just edit my post and I still need some help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution :

```
Sub CopyShtInOtherWb()
 Dim Wb As Workbook

 Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test2.xlsm")
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Worksheet to Another Workbook

- At this stage, I would suggest you 'go the extra mile': `Workbook - Worksheet - Range` i.e. use variables.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportWorksheet1()
  
    Const sName As String = "Bilan_SAJMA"
  
    Const dPath As String = "C:\Users\33672\Documents\test01.xlsm"
    Const dIndex As Long = 4 ' often not such a good idea
  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(sName)
  
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dPath)
    Dim dsh As Object: Set dsh = dwb.Sheets(dIndex) ' could be a chart
  
    sws.Copy Before:=dsh
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

- Of course, you could do (not recommended)...

```vb
Sub ExportWorksheetShort()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bilan_SAJMA").Copy Before:= _
        Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\33672\Documents\test01.xlsm").Sheets(4)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

but it's getting harder to find the reason behind a possibly occurring error.

### EDIT

- If the worksheet is very hidden, you will have to use the following ('simply' hidden worksheets are covered by the first version (above)).

```vb
Sub ExportWorksheet()
  
    Const sName As String = "Bilan_SAJMA"
  
    Const dPath As String = "F:\Test\2021\68019811\test01.xlsm" ' "C:\Users\33672\Documents\test01.xlsm"
    Const dIndex As Long = 4 ' often not such a good idea
  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(sName)
  
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dPath)
    Dim dsh As Object: Set dsh = dwb.Sheets(dIndex) ' could be a chart
  
    If sws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
        sws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        sws.Copy Before:=dsh
        sws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        'ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden ' The copy stays very hidden.
    Else
        sws.Copy Before:=dsh
    End If
    
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

' To delete all sheets containing "Bilan_SAJMA" in workbook 'test01.xlsm'.
Sub DeleteSheetsNotContainingTEST()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("test01.xlsm")
    DeleteSheetsContaining wb, "Bilan_SAJMA"
End Sub

' To unhide all sheets in 'Thisworkbook'.
Sub UnhideSheetsTEST()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    UnhideSheets wb
End Sub

Sub DeleteSheetsContaining( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal StringContained As String)
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim shNames() As String
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If InStr(1, sh.Name, StringContained, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            If sh.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
                sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            End If
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve shNames(1 To n)
            shNames(n) = sh.Name
        End If
    Next sh
    
    If n = 0 Then Exit Sub
        
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Sheets(shNames).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Sub UnhideSheets(ByVal wb As Workbook)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: When I run this code without anything else I get this error :  compile error - required object to the line : Dim dsh As Object: Set dsh = dwb.Sheets(dIndex) . I don't know if it's important or not but I also have multiple hidden Sheet in my workbook

Comment: That's an unexplainable error to me. When something like this happens, I usually recreate the whole workbook. A run-time error would occur if the `Source Worksheet` (`Bilan_SAJMA`) was very hidden. I'll be adding the code to remedy this and some other code that helped me study this.

Comment: Sadly the target sheet is not hidden. I will try to re make the workbook

Comment: Is anyone can please try one of my sub in my edited post to tel me if it's working for you or not ?